# Object required Run-time error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of checkboxes and after some of them are checked I would like to know which ones are checked so I can work with those checked boxes. Not sure why these few lines don't work. After I execute it there is a pop up error message saying "Object required" Run-time error '424': and highlights line => ReDim SelectedItemArray(ListBox1.ListCount) As String. Yes I have four ListBoxes; ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
Sub CheckedBoxes()

Dim SelectedItemArray() As String

ReDim SelectedItemArray(ListBox1.ListCount) As String

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
SelectedItemArray(i) = ListBox1.List(i)
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try fully qualifying the listbox.  For example `Sheet1.ListBox1.ListCount`.

Comment: Listbox is on a worksheet or a userform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully qualifying the listbox. For example `Sheet1.ListBox1.ListCount`

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I use for ListBoxes on a UserForm. I modified it (further below) for use on Worksheet listboxes.

For form controls ListBox on a UserForm, call it like:

```
myArray = GetSelectedItems(ListBox1)
```

Here's the function which will accept *any* listbox from a UserForm as a named argument:

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As Variant
'returns an array of selected items in a ListBox
Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer

        selCount = -1
        For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
            If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
                selCount = selCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
                tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.List(i)

            End If
        Next
        If selCount = -1 Then
            GetSelectedItems = Array()
        Else:
            GetSelectedItems = tmpArray
        End If
End Function
```

If you are referring to a ListBox on a worksheet, try this instead:

Call it like this:

```
myArray = GetSelectedItems(Sheet1.Shapes("List Box 1").OLEFormat.Object)
```

Here's the function modified for Worksheet form control ListBox:

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lBox As Object) As Variant
'returns an array of selected items in a ListBox
Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer

        selCount = -1
        For i = 1 To lBox.ListCount - 1
            If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
                selCount = selCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
                tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.List(i)

            End If
        Next
        If selCount = -1 Then
            GetSelectedItems = Array()
        Else:
            GetSelectedItems = tmpArray
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much David. I sure appreciate you help.